# старый код адаптировать под новые рабочие библиотеки

Tags: python

Я только начинаю знакомиться с Python. 
Код должен скачивать торрент файлы с трекера.
Код работает на Python 2. 
Помогите перевести код на Python 3.
Взял этот кусок кода отсюда: [ссылка](http://python.su/forum/topic/11899/?page=1#post-73995)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim: sw=4 ts=4 expandtab ai

import os
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

def main(args):
    login, password, topic_id, outf = args

    # prepare opener with cookie handling
    cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies))
    data = urllib.urlencode({'login_username': login,
                              'login_password': password,
                              'login': ''})

    # login
    opener.open('http://login.rutracker.org/forum/login.php', data)

    # open torrent url
    torrent_url = 'http://dl.rutracker.org/forum/dl.php?t=%s' % topic_id
    handle = opener.open(torrent_url, data)

    # write it to output file
    out = open(outf, 'wb')
    out.write(handle.read())
    out.close()

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 5:
        print "Usage: %s <login> <password> <topic id> <output file>" % \
                  os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: Данный код написан под Python 2, вот его и используйте, всё заработает без установки каких-либо библиотек

Comment: 1- Если цель — запустить скрипт, то поставьте Python 2 версию. Если цель — Питон выучить, то сперва одну версию языка освойте в достаточном для вас объёме и только потом о можно учить разницу между версиями (в данном случае, если код работал на Питоне 3, то возможно достаточно импорты поправить, чтобы Питон 3 версию скрипта получить). 2- в текущей постановке вопрос в заголовке слишком широк. Попробуйте сузить задачу к конкретной проблеме.

Comment: код заработал на python2 теперь нужно перевести его на python3